# change the font style of text as other text

Tags: html, css, fonts

in above image you can see text  "acceptable".
[image]

i want to change this **font** as text "contact us" font which is present below.

we are using

```
 font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
```

but it didt worked for us.

Comment: Well it is working. just difference of font-size nothing else.

Comment: thats right, i didt observed, please post as an asnwer.

Comment: you can use `<span></span> ` tag ,please look at following my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to your code, you just have to change the `font-size` of p tag and you are done. To check the changes try to add Contact us next to  acceptable and then you will see both are same. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `<span class="red">text</span>` and some basic CSS like `.red { color: red;` }
[lOOK AT THIS EXAMPLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/wuyahggh/1/)

**HTML**

```
     <span class="red">acceptable</span>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {color: black;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: justify;
    }

    .red { color: red;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; }
```

Comment: same thing , you can change it

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe  ,you're not understand my answer,please look at my point, just example, its not my text , he is updated question, im not saw it

Comment: i  removed the text